# git how to change default branch for everything I do?

Tags: git, github, git-branch

Because of github changing the default branch from master to main all of my pushes end up in a separate branch instead of the main one and I can't change the default. When I start a program and make my first push, git tells me main doesn't exist and I always have to push to master instead.

Comment: Look at this [GitHub](https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/changing-the-default-branch)-Doc.

Comment: I'm having this issue with Gitea

Comment: What a complete waste of time.

Answer (score 68):

Following the FAQ article "[How to Rename the master branch to main in Git](https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/faq/git-rename-master-to-main/)", and the [GitHub documentation  itself](https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/changing-the-default-branch), you can:

- rename your local branch from master to main: `git branch -m master main`
- push to main: `git push -u origin main`
- update your default branch on GitHub side:
  [image]
- Then delete the remote master branch: `git push origin --delete master`

Finally, as I documented in "[How can I create a Git repository with the default branch name other than "`master`"?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62983443/6309)", don't forget a:

```
git config --global init.defaultBranch main
```

(See [commit 32ba12d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/32ba12dab2acf1ad11836a627956d1473f6b851a), with Git 2.28+, Q3 2020)

Your next new repositories will use the right branch name by default.

Answer (score 21):

Another way to change your default branch in your local machine, as pointed [here](https://superuser.com/a/1646424), is to edit your ~/.gitconfig file and add or edit the following lines:

```
[init]
  defaultBranch = main
```

I prefer this option because I've already had a bunch of configurations in my ~/.gitconfig file, so for me is better to lock it before and check whether the wanted configuration exists or not and if yes how it's set.

Comment: this is the same as `git config --global init.defaultBranch main`

Comment: @cynicaljoy Indeed it's the same, but still people could prefer this way of editing

Answer (score 3):

To change the default branch globally for all projects, configure `git` to do so, by issuing the following command

`$ git config --global init.defaultBranch main`
The `--global` option sets this systemwide. You can use `--local` also which is the default for a given project.